# How can i show interstitial admob by click button moving to the next scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

How can i show the interstitial ad admob in the action of click button to move in to the next scene,
I'm already trying something which one you will see in bellow.

Can you help me please ?

*first method i'm creating a gameobject and add the script Admanager in there and connect the game object with button who's using to move in to the next scene, 
-note button next scene already with On Click gameobject Admanger with RequestInterstitial and ShowInterstitial....

*second method as well directly in the script i add in the method move to the next scene ShowInterstitial and in gamemanager script with void start RequestInterstitial,
-note i change Request... by ShowInter... and is still doesn't working

Script GameManager

```
private void Start()
    {
        //Show Banner
        AdManager.Instance.RequestBanner();
        //Interstitial Preparing
        AdManager.Instance.Invoke("RequestInterstitial", 0.5f);
        //Interstitial Preparing

    }
//Note: i'm trying with void update too
```

Script ButtonsManager

```
public void Level2btn()
    {
        //Interstitial Showing
        AdManager.Instance.Invoke("ShowIinterstitial", 0.5f);
        //Interstitial Showing
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
```

By the way, this's the script of AdManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{

       public static AdManager Instance { get; set; }

    public bool interstitialLoaded = false;
    public bool interstitialClosed = false;

    const string interstitialAdId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    const string bannerADid = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    AdRequest request;
    private BannerView bannerview;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitialAdId);
        Showbanner();

        request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
    }
    public void RequestBanner()
    {
        bannerview = new BannerView(bannerADid, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.TopRight);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        bannerview.LoadAd(request);
        bannerview.Show();
    }
    public void Showbanner()
    {
        if(bannerview ==  null)
        {
            RequestBanner();
        }
    }
    public void InvokeLoadAd()
    {
        Invoke("ShowIintertitial", 2.0f);
    }
    public void InvokeAd()
    {
        Invoke("ShowIintertitial", 2.0f);
    }

    public void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
    }
    public void ShowIintertitial()
    {

        if(interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitialLoaded = true;
            interstitialAd.Show();

        }
        interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += InterstitialAd_onAdClosed;
    }

    private void InterstitialAd_onAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might need to see more code to figure out everything going on but a couple things you could check.

1) Are you calling your method `Level2btn()` on the OnClick for the button in the inspector?

2) Also, might want to double check your spelling (ShowIinterstitial has an extra I) to make sure it matches the method you are trying to call:

`AdManager.Instance.Invoke("ShowIinterstitial", 0.5f);`

Comment: Yes i do, the thing is everything of ads inside the same scene it working as well, just when i try show ads interstitial or videorewards in step of moving to another, so the ads doesn't appear